# How To Populate A Gridview Dynamically Using Multiple Queries

Tags: sql, gridview

I have two tables, `UserInfo` (PrimaryKey= UID) and `Relationships` (PrimaryKey= RID, ForeignKey= UID).
Relationships data example:

```
| UID | RID |

|  2  |  3  |

|  3  |  4  |
```

Now, after executing an sql query, that performs some sorting on Relationships table like:

```
"select RID from Relationships where UID= "value"
UNION select UID from Relationships where RID= "value "
```

if the value = 3, i get the integer values such 2 , 4 (which means 3 has relationships with 2 and 4)

if value = 4, result = 3 (4 only has relationship with 3)

etc these resulting values are PrimaryKey values of the `UserInfo` table.

What i want to do is to fetch the Information of Users having the `UID` = 23,25,34 (These values are the result of first SQL query, so the number of values and values changes every time according to the values passed to first SQL query)
and bind it with an asp Gridview.

for this, i think i'll have to execute multiple sql queries like

```
select * from UserInfo where UID= 2

select * from UserInfo where UID= 4
```

etc

using a loop.

What i think i should do is to loop through the results of first sql query, execute the second query according to it and save the resulting recordset in another table or any sort of datasource, which is finally bind to the gridview... but i don't know how to implement it..

this is my first question in StackOverflow.. i'll try my best to further clarrify the problem if necessory..

any help would be greatly appreciatable..! :)

Comment: Can't you do `SELECT * FROM userInfo WHERE UID IN (`List of UID OR query goes here `)`

Comment: Can you explain your tables a little better?  `UID` is Foreign Key in `Friendships` pointing to `UID` in `UserInfo` and `FID` is the Id for the record.  What is the column for the other user? (I assume your Friend table is something like `ID | UserID1 | UserID2 | etc.`)

Comment: i'm actually passing the sql query into a constructor which takes 2 parameters, the query string and gridview name. i was quite exited about the nested query, which i never even thought of before.. but as a whole it becomes the following: dbo.fillGrid("select * from UserInfo where UID IN("select RID from Relationships where UID= " value " union select UID from Relationships where RID= " value " ")"), GridView1); which confuses the compiler about the number of arguments i think..! :( thanks for your effort i'll do some more research for doing it using nested queries :)

Comment: wow... finally it worked out..! thanks a lot for redirecting me in the right path..!

the final sql query is as follows: "select * from UserInfo where UID in(select RID from Relationships where UID= " value " union select UID from Relationships where FID= " value ") "

Answer (score 1):

You can use a SQL join

```
select a.RID from Friendships a inner join Relationships b on a.uid=b.uid 
where a.UID= "value" & b.RID="value"
order by a.uid
```

This will give you all records which exist in both tables A & B.[More on SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

There is no need to loop as you can execute the query in a single SQL statement like

```
select * from UserInfo where UID IN (23, 25, 34);
```

On a short note, `select * from table` is usually a bad practise & you might want to replace it with your column names

Comment: after trying it, i further updated the question with an example of relationships table.. if i use inner join a.UID=b.UID, suppose UID= 3, it will only fetch the second row, so the result will be 2 only, while actually there exists a relationship between 3 and 4, but won't be fetched since it is in the reverse order (3 is in RID field, not UID)
to solve this, i'll have to add two rows for each relationship such as 3,4 and 4,3.. :(

union query avoids this problem but i stil can't figure out how to fetch data from UserInfo table with it's results :(

Comment: @TilwinJoy You can look into various types of other joins (INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, FULL).